# How to click on <option> inside <select> Python

Tags: python, html, selenium

I want to click on a certain option by id.. the problem is above the select I've got

```
<ul style="display: block; visibility: visible;"><li><a href="#" index="0" class="" onclick="s_objectID=&quot;https://viajemais.voeazul.com.br/Contact.aspx#_573&quot;;return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">....
```

thats what becomes visible when if I click the dropdown button
and than I have the select

```
<select id="ControlGroupContact_ContactInputView_DropDownListStateProvince" name="ControlGroupContact$ContactInputView$DropDownListStateProvince" readonly="false" class="jqTransformHidden"><option selected="" value="">Escolha um</option>
                <option value="BR|AC">Acre</option>...
```

I've tryied to use that code:

```
countries_dropdown = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name('countryBR')
    countries_dropdown.click()
    country_dropdown = Select(countries_dropdown.find_element_by_id('ControlGroupContact_ContactInputView_DropDownListCountry'))

    country_dropdown.select_by_value(payer_details.country_code.upper())
```

so I'm even opening the dropdown even if I open and even if I dont open the drop down, the error im getting is

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=44.0.2403.125)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `jqTransformHidden` class makes it hidden. Remove the class and make it visible:

```
dropdown = countries_dropdown.find_element_by_id('ControlGroupContact_ContactInputView_DropDownListCountry')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].className = '';", dropdown)
```

Comment: now i can click but its doesnt seem to be really clicking cause the dropdown stays open and the states dropdown is empty

Comment: @DorAlt btw, have you tried to click the dropdown first to open it up and then click an option?

Comment: That moment when you realize that when you copy pasted and than chang something and something got deleted? thats what happend and I'm sitting on it since yesterday

Thank you